# Read File in Java, output the first comma delimited String

Tags: java, string, file-io

I want to extract the first `String` in a file using the delimiter ",".
Why does this code generate a number of lines greater than one?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("irisAfter.txt"));
        String read = null;
        while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
            read = in.readLine();
            String[] splited = read.split(",");
            for (int i =0; i<splited.length;i++) {
                System.out.println(splited[0]);
            } 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what your question is? This site is to give direction or answer but not to write your code for you.

Comment: Why are you printing out the same word over and over to the console?

Comment: Also you are skipping 1 line and reading the next in every iteration.

Answer (score 5):

You are printing inside a loop. That's why it is printing multiple times (if that's what you're asking).

```
String[] splited = read.split(",");    
System.out.println(splited[0]);
```

will just do

**EDIT**: As Abishek also mentioned, don't `read = in.readLine();` again inside your `while` loop since by doing so you are skipping a line.

```
while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] splited = read.split(",");
   System.out.println(splited[0]);
}
```

Comment: Essentially just move the contents of the for loop out of it and remove the for loop all together.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by number of lines superior to the original ones

If you are using `splited[0]`, why are you keeping inside a loop. It will always get you same string

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why your code works that way but you might try Scanner with a delimeter.  Try:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner( new File("myNumbers")).useDelimiter(",");
String firstString = sc.next(); 
/// check for null..
```

Answer (score 2):

You read in every line from "irisAfter.txt", then split each line on "," into multiple elements, then print out the first element of that line on its own line as many times as there are elements in the line. Multiple lines*multiple elements per line = more lines in output than in input.

Change

```
for (int i =0; i<splited.length;i++) {
      System.out.println(splited[0]);

}
```

to

```
if (splited.length > 0)
{
     System.out.println(splited[0]);
}
```

That way you print out the first element of every line on its own line only one time and only if there actually is a first element.

You are also skipping every other line. If you don't want to do that, remove the line 
`read = in.readLine();`
just below 
`while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {`.

(You are now reading in a line and then reading in the next line, discarding the first read in line. Then you process that second line, after which the loop starts again, you read in the third line, then read in the fourth line, discarding the third, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 1):

if you modify your code like this, you should get the result you expect.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            String[] splited;
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("irisAfter.txt"));
            String read = null;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                read = in.readLine();
                splited = read.split(",");
            }

            System.out.println(splited[0]);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
}
```