# Java - Take text from file and assign matching parameter text to matching object

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn java and this is the method of this employee project i'm trying to learn, I need to take in a file ( which i have and it works because I can print the results ) and assign the correct lines to either a technician object or a salesman object, noted by a leading T or S in the beginning of the line like :

For a Technician :  T,String,int,int,String,  for the appropriate fields.

For a Salesman   :   S,String,int,double,String,  for the appropriate fields.

---

file.txt

S,Mohamed,274533,56000.0,CEO,

T,Mike,19283748,2,CFO,

---

So once it reads each line it should put it in either a Salesman Object or Technician Object. So far i can just output the file as is. How do I assign it and then return an Employee array?

```
public Object[] loadArray(String fileName) throws IOException {    
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     list.add(line);
        System.out.println(line);
    }   

    if (bufferedReader != null) {
        bufferedReader.close();
    }

    return employees;
}
```

Comment: First, you need an Employee class. I strongly recommend reading the Java tutorial online at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: I have all the classes, this is another method in my file.java. And I have to call it in a main method in the company class.

Comment: I recommend splitting the line into the desired fields and setting them in your while loop. A similar question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052825/read-file-in-java-output-the-first-comma-delimited-string You may also want to check out this link on how to parse strings using split: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just split each line using the comma as a delimiter

eg.

`String[] tokens = line.split(",");`

You can then assign each token as needed.

Comment: How would I use that?